# Combinations of an amount distributed over time

Tags: python, algorithm, math

Let's say I have an item that become available to met in a certain volume, at a certain time :

| Item | Week 1 | Week 2 | Week 3 | Week 4 | Week 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item 1 | 100 | 0 | 0 | 200 | 0 |

I'd like to distribute this product over all these weeks and test all combinations possible. To reduce the combinations I'd like to work only with 50 units (we can change this variable) and  I can't distribute an amount that will be available later. In the above example I can distribute only 2x 50 units during the first 3 weeks.

For instance :

| Item | Week 1 | Week 2 | Week 3 | Week 4 | Week 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Combination 1 | 50 | 50 | 0 | 100 | 100 |
| Combination 2 | 0 | 50 | 50 | 50 | 150 |
| .. | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

How would be the best way to create this kind of algorithm ?

Thanks for the help

Comment: Have you heard of combinatorics? Look up combination formula-- I don't know what the actual algorithm would be because your problem has more depth, but It could be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer, recursion.  Also since the answer may be long, use generators to avoid running out of memory.

Fuller answer:

```
def combinations(inputs, unit=50):
    def recur (i, carried_forward):
        available = carried_forward + inputs[i]
        if i+1 == len(inputs):
            yield [available] # Have to use it all.
        else:
            # 0 through available in steps of unit
            for used in range(0, available + unit, unit):
                for remaining_solution in recur(i+1, available - used):
                    remaining_solution.insert(0, used)
                    yield remaining_solution

    for answer in recur(0, 0):
        yield answer

for comb in combinations([100, 0, 0, 200, 0]):
    print(comb)
```